# Should I keep a registry of child actors?

Tags: akka.net, actor-model

I recently started working on a system, and I am using Akka.NET. I am still learning how to think in the terms of the actor model, so I would be open to suggestions from the more experienced.

I try to ask a more general question first:

**How to keep track of child actor state by a manager entity in order to make decisions on which child to interact with**, if the decision must be based on a number of parameters and complex business rules distributed in multiple actor classes.

I'll try to simplify the problem I am facing:
Let's say I have an Actor System, and there is an actor, called **Backlog**.

The **Backlog** is responsible for creating and supervising **Jobs** (also actors).

**Jobs** have a lifecycle, for the sake of simplicity they can be either **Active** or **Completed**. They are created Active, and turn Completed when receiving a specific message. Completion does not mean termination. That comes later, at some point (so no deathwatch). **Jobs** can be and eventually are associated with **Resources**. One **Job** might be associated with zero, one or many **Resources**.

**Resources** are actors *not supervised* by the **Backlog**. There is a limited number of **Resources**.

**Only one active Job can be associated with a Resource at any time.**

It is possible that a **Resource** is not associated with a **Job**.
It is possible that a **Resource** is not aware of being associated with a **Job**.

**Resources** are sometimes **detected** by sensors. The **Detector** will need to know the *Intention* of the **Resource**. The *Intention* is part of the mutatable state of the **Job**.

A **Resource** does not have an *Intention* on it's own, only when being associated with the **Job**, but it needs to state an *Intention* when being asked, so it needs to ensure there is a **Job** associated. (As the detector detects Resources, and not Jobs.)

In my design the **Resource** needs to ask the **Backlog** for a **Job**, if it does not have one when being detected.

Now the **Backlog** may or may not have a **Job** for this resource. If it does not, it should create one (let's say it knows how to). In order to do that it needs to know which of its **Jobs** are active and if any of those is already associated with the **Resource** that was asking.

Still with me?

So how should I make **Backlog** find out, whether it has a **Job** for **Resource R**? Should I broadcast a message to all the Job actors and ask them if they are active? And also if they are accidentally handling **R**? How do I make sure all **Jobs** did actually process it and how much should I wait for them to do it (especially since 0 ms seems to be the only acceptable performance for such simple tasks).

Or should I keep dictionaries holding **Job** actor references by **Resource** identifiers? And also by (last known) states involved in this decision? And then how should I maintain these dictionaries? Looking for Domain events? Or introduce yet more messages for **Jobs** to tell **Backlog** about their state changes with at-least-once guarantees?

To be honest, I love the mindset and the benefits of using the actor model, but the sheer amount of code here required to implement functionality that would be like a single line of LINQ query in the traditional OO makes me worried about how willing the rest of the team will be to handle this code.

**SUMMARIZING**

I have an actor *Backlog* responsible for creating and supervising *Jobs*, other actors that represent a concept in the domain. On some occassions, it needs to select *exactly one* of these Jobs based on some criteria involving the mutable state of the child actors, or determine if there is no job currently available. (Having multiple suitable jobs indicates a problem and should be detected.)

**Question:** Do I have optioins other than broadcasting some message to all jobs, containing criteria and waiting for each of the jobs to apply this criteria to themselves respond with a positive or negative answer?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you described a lot, some important details are missing, for example are the backlogs processed in FIFO? it is important for the solution.

1. For example if they do, I would use some queue such as RabbitMQ which actors can pull tasks when they are ready, this way the backlog actor should not even care, it is just dispatching a job into the appropriate queue.
2. If you don't care exactly about the order, you can use routers and send the request (command/message) to one of the |R| job actors, and use for example the smallest queue size routing strategy.

If I will answer to the primarily question, one way of doing this configure the  manager to receive commands which updates the child status and update this internally, it is easy and will not require more than a Dictionary in the Manager actor since it is guarantee to be executing single command at a time.

The relation to LINQ does not seems to be clear to me at all for you have described unless something fundamentally missing in your question.

Comment: Thanks, @Yoav. I'll try to clarify a bit. The main issue here is that when Resource R tells the backlog to assign it a job, the backlog needs to know, which is suitable and select exactly one. If none is suitable, it should create a new one. The suitability of a job cannot be determined from the jobs identity, it depends on state, that the actors hide. My current approach is to create a 'poll' by broadcasting a criteria to each job and wait for all of them to ACK or NACK.

Comment: With the relation to the LINQ query I just meant that in "traditional" OOP the backlog would just have a collection of jobs, and I would select the proper one like `jobs.Where(job.ResourceId == rId && job.State == JobState.Active).SingleOrDefault()`. Since actors hide their state, I have to do much much more work than this. I appreciate the benefits of the actor model, I just see a **LOT** of convincing my team in my near future, and it makes me somewhat concerned. :)